# Can't connect to all tables in mySQL database using excel pivot table

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin, odbc

I'm trying to build pivot table in excel using the mysql database I've created on my host using myphpadmin.
The problem - that I can't connect to all tables at once, although I choose all of them:
[image]

it only shows me one table at once:
[image]

I connect to the data using ODBC DNS.

Here is some info of the database:

[Printable view of the database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pQRe9QUB4Bz7d1j-fkX1V_pAG8Hif_-/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Might be helpful - I've noticed that excel doesn't recognize the relations in the database:

[image]

Sorry for the long post, thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Are you using power pivot?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, I have Excel 2016